# JavaScript передача переменых

Tags: javascript, сокет, websocket, переменные, сокеты

Есть сокет с установленным соеденением, как при переходе на новую страницу сохранить сокет, и другие переменные?

Comment: хранить данные в локал сторадж

Comment: Соединения сохранять на диск нельзя. При переходе на новую страницу вам нужно заново устанавливать соединение.

Comment: Можно сделать "окно" (например `<div>`), и грузить страницы в окно, используя подзапросы (например JQuery или Ajax). А переходы по ссылкам сделать через `javascript:f(x);` ccылки. Для "прямого" попадания, использовать #-часть урла.